# Requests are not served from the nearest region in aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I have a video streaming application and my client is from Maldives. The nearest AWS region for Maldives is Asia Pacific Mumbai. I had set up CDN and now most of the requests from Maldives are served from Singapore region even though Mumbai is the nearest region. Why is it so?

Comment: can you please add what you have tried to achieve this, so that I can help....

Comment: Can you measure the time it takes for packets traveling from Mumbai to Maldives, and the time it takes for packets traveling from Singapore to Maldives?

Comment: I guess packets sent from Singapore to Maldives takes less time. That's why requests are mostly not served from Mumbai.

Comment: @Brian: How can I check that, is it available in the console.

Comment: @Jijo please clarify how you determined that requests are being served from Singapore.  If you are using CloudFront, I would have expected the term you used to be "edge location" rather than "region" (because CloudFront's edge location footprint doesn't exactly align with the same geography as the AWS regions) and the fact that you say "region" suggests that we need to clarify exactly what you are observing.

Answer (score 0):

I presume that you are using **Amazon CloudFront** to serve the video.

CloudFront uses many methods, such as AnyCast, to determine from where to serve traffic. Typically, it will serve content from an edge location that provide **better performance** in terms of network latency. This will **not necessarily be the closest physical location**.

In fact, some cities have more than one edge location so that major ISPs can be better serviced via fast network connections.

Answer (score 0):

One best way to start troubleshoot the problem is to:

1. Get one IP of India POP (BOM/DEL/HYD/BLR) and perform MTR to see if we see better latency compare to when you connect to Singapore.

If so:

2. Try 8.8.8.8 as a resolver on a test machine, this supports EDNS and check if you get any India pop.
3. At last, perform dig/nslookup resolver-identity.cloudfront.net and provide your resolver IP to AWS to see which edge location is best for you or if they can fix anything for you.